# Why does the bibliography look messy after compilation?

Tags: bibtex

I use the standard BibTeX setup, like the code below. It will compile, but it does not look nice afterward in the bibliography, as seen in the picture. What can I do to fix it?

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\begin{thebibliography}{99}

@book{moeslund2012introduction,
title={Introduction to video and image processing: Building real systems and applications},
author={Moeslund, Thomas B},
year={2012},
publisher={Springer Science \& Business Media}
}
\end{thebibliography}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post a minimal compilable code example (please integrate this sample of the external `.bib` file into the "real" document using `filecontents`).

Comment: *How* did you compile?

Comment: Well, as it seems you are using `thebibliography`. That's not the correct way to use BibTeX. Please have a look at BibTeX starter guides.

Comment: @Mico Yes, that was an suggested edit which is now in the question. That also explains the problem.

Comment: At the very first, you have to decide what tools (if any) you want to use. Please have a look at [this page](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Creating_a_Bibliography).

Answer (score 3):

It would appear that you are -- contrary to your claim -- *not* using BibTeX at all. Instead, it appears you're abusing/misusing the `thebibliography` environment, which should never be used in conjunction with BibTeX.

Run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more on the following test document to experience how to do things the right way. (The biliography file is called `mybib.bib` in the example code; feel free to choose a different name.)

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@book{moeslund2012introduction,
    title={Introduction to video and image processing: 
           Building real systems and applications},
    author={Moeslund, Thomas B.},
    year={2012},
    publisher={Springer Science \& Business Media}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\bibliographystyle{plain}

\begin{document}
\cite{moeslund2012introduction}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```